# How can I split a string into 3 Parts, even if the delimiter exists more than twice

Tags: regex, string, shell, sed, split

I have a linux receiver and want to rename the recordings. Recordings look like
`20131018 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of the movie.ts`

I want to get only "Name of the movie.ts". I can easily do this by using the following sed- command:

```
echo 20131018 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of the movie.ts|sed 's!\(.*\) - \(.*\) - \(.*\)!\3!'
```

BUT: if the name of the movie contains the separator " - " as well, then it will cut it off at the separator:

```
echo 20131018 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of another movie - Second part.ts|sed 's!\(.*\) - \(.*\) - \(.*\)!\3!'
```

will output:

Name of another movie

instead of

Name of another movie - Second part.ts

How can I achieve this?

Thanx

Comment: If you add `^` in the start of your regex it's impossible for it to refer to the 3 last, but the last would be greedy and take the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` matches as much as possible (greedy).

Replace `.` with `[^-]`:

```
$ filename='20131018 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of another movie - Second part.ts'
$ echo $filename | sed 's!\([^-]*\) - \([^-]*\) - \([^-]*\)!\3!'
Name of another movie - Second part.ts
```

Without capturing group:

```
$ echo $filename | sed 's![^-]* - [^-]* - !!'
Name of another movie - Second part.ts
```

Comment: This `sed 's!\([^-]*\) - \([^-]*\) - \([^-]*\)!\3!'` can be shorten to `sed 's![^-]* - [^-]* - \([^-]*\)!\1!'`, you do not need all the references.

Comment: The second example is very easy and works perfectly for all examples I could find! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For spliting strings you may prefer using 'cut' command:

your string to replace:

```
filename='20131018 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of another movie - Second part.ts'
```

the command to apply:

```
echo $filename | cut -d\- -f3-
```

- -d: define the separator
- -f: define the columns to extract

ex:

- -f3    : return 3rd column
- -f3-5  : return columns 3 to 5
- -f1,3- : return columns 1 and 3 to end of line(s)

Comment: Your answer seems to fit the best for the original problem, but the answer I accepted is closer to the question regarding sed... But nevertheless: thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and regex from falsetru example

```
cat file
20131018 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of another movie - First part.ts
20131019 2245 - Channel 1 - Name of another movie - Second part.ts
20131022 1520 - Channel 3 - A good movie.ts
```

```
awk '{sub(/[^-]* - [^-]* - /,x)}1' file
Name of another movie - First part.ts
Name of another movie - Second part.ts
A good movie.ts
```

---

A gnu `awk version` (alo copy regex from falsetru)
This using back reference

```
awk '{print gensub(/[^-]* - [^-]* - ([^-]*)/,"\\1","g")}' file
```